# I need use is_single in functions.php

Tags: conditional-tags

I need to use validation is_single('wordpress') in file functions.php.

But the function is_single() does not work in the file functions.php.

What can I do so that I can use is_single() in file functions.php?

If more, then:

I'm doing a check, its single page or not.

And for single page I am set custom function..

Please help me someone.

Comment: Please share your code. You probably need to find the right hook to attach it to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`is_single` most likely only works inside of [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), and `functions.php` loads before you're in The Loop.

You could try something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){
    var_dump(is_single());
});
```

And now you see that `is_single()` returns `true`.

EDIT: I was probably off for suggesting it only works inside The Loop, but there's definitely better places for `is_single` than in `functions.php`, and if you're checking the "singleness" of a page, wait until you're in the request proper, or the template, to use it.

Comment: Depending on the context they're running the function in, is_single() might work because it's a request on the main WP_Query itself, not dependent upon when functions.php itself loads.

Comment: @socki03 I would say from some basic testing that this is not the case. For example, on a mostly vanilla WP install I dumped `is_single` in `functions.php` when loading a Post and the result was `false`, however, waiting until I was "in" the template (e.g. `wp_head`), the `is_single` check worked fine.

Comment: `is_single` is set in the [`parse_query` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/), which is several actions later than when the `functions.php` file is initially loaded, but still several actions before the template is loaded.

Comment: Yes, but the idea behind the functions file is to parse a bunch of functions that are run at different times in the loading process, most of which are traditionally after `parse_query` is already run.  If you need to run `is_single` from the functions file, you should probably be running it in the template itself, and not in the functions file.  Unless you're reusing it.  All that being said, we need to see the initial code to make a judgement call.

Comment: I use conditional statements quite often outside the loop, ie. for conditional including scripts in `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Answer (score 3):

Fresh from the Codex:

> Warning: You can only use conditional query tags after the posts_selection action hook in WordPress (the wp action hook is the first one through which you can use these conditionals). **For themes, this means the conditional tag will never work properly if you are using it in the body of functions.php, i.e. outside of a function.**
>
> However: if you have a reference to the query object (for example, from within the parse_query or pre_get_posts hooks), you can use the WP_Query conditional methods (eg: $query->is_search())

https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags